# Properties are not getting passed to component while making it render

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have 3 components container, A and B component. Container contain both A and B.
I am passing some properties from A to B via message channel. I am making the cmp A disable and showing the cmp B but the values are not flowing. There is a timer method after 60 seconds it will trigger the handleTimerComplete() method. My thinking is that the values are stored in channel and it should print them when I am enabling the component but that is not happening. What is the issue  I am not sure. Can please somebody help me on this. Thanks.

```
cmpA.js
    import { MessageContext, publish } from 'lightning/messageService';
import samplemc from '@salesforce/messageChannel/transferInfo__c';
    @wire(MessageContext)
    context

    timer() {
        const trueVal=true;
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.countDownTimer--;
            if (this.countDownTimer <= 0) {
                clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
                this.handleTimerComplete()
                //this.navigateToEndTemplate();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    publishMessage(){
        const message={
            lmsData:{
                value1:this.correctAnswerCounter,
                value2:this.questionCounter
            }
        }

        publish(this.context, samplemc, message)
    }
    handleTimerComplete(){
        const val=true
        const timercompleteevent = new CustomEvent("answer", 
            {
                detail:val
            });
        this.dispatchEvent(timercompleteevent);
    }
```

Now I have the container component

```
containerCmp.js 
<template>
    <div>
        <template if:true={showComponentA} >
            <c-cat-api onanswer={handleTimerComplete} ></c-cat-api>
        </template>
        <template if:true={showComponentB} >
            <c-end-screen></c-end-screen>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

js part

import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';

export default class ContainerCmp extends LightningElement {
    @track showComponentA=true;
    @track showComponentB=false;

    handleTimerComplete(event) {
        if(event.detail){
            this.showComponentA = false;
            this.showComponentB = true;
        }else{
            consolole.log('!!error is coming up!!');
        }
    }
}
```

now component B

```
js part
    receivedMessage1;
    receivedMessage2;

    @wire(MessageContext)
    context

    renderedCallback(){
        this.subscribeMessage();
    }

    subscribeMessage(){
        subscribe(this.context,samplemc,(message)=>{this.handleMessage(message)},{scope:APPLICATION_SCOPE})
    }

    handleMessage(message){
        this.receivedMessage1 = message.lmsData.value1? message.lmsData.value1:"NO MESSAGE DELIVERED 1"
        this.receivedMessage2 = message.lmsData.value2? message.lmsData.value2:"NO MESSAGE DELIVERED 2"
    }
```

html part for cmpB

```
<template>
    <div>correct answers <strong>{receivedMessage1}</strong></div>
    <div>total number of questions attempted <strong>{receivedMessage2}</strong> </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscriber must be subscribed before the publisher publishes, or the message won't be received. Unlike Platform Events, there's no queue or cache for LMS messages, and they can't be replayed. It's like trying to talk to someone on the phone before they've picked up the call. Instead, either have the parent component store the values and pass them from A to B, or use `slds-hide` to hide the component but still have it be in the DOM.

Edit:

Here's an example using `slds-hide`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <c-cat-api class={catApiClass} onanswer={handleTimerComplete} ></c-cat-api>
    <c-end-screen class={endScreenClass}></c-end-screen>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';

export default class ContainerCmp extends LightningElement {
    catApiClass = '';
    endScreenClass = 'slds-hide';

    handleTimerComplete(event) {
        if(event.detail){
            this.catApiClass = 'slds-hide';
            this.endScreenClass = '';
        }else{
            consolole.log('!!error is coming up!!');
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what storing the value would look like:

```
    timer() {
        const trueVal=true;
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.countDownTimer--;
            if (this.countDownTimer <= 0) {
                clearInterval(this.countDownInterval);
                this.handleTimerComplete()
                //this.navigateToEndTemplate();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    handleTimerComplete(){
        const timercompleteevent = new CustomEvent("answer", 
            {
                detail: {
                  timeUp: true,
                  value1: this.correctAnswerCounter,
                  value2:this.questionCounter
                }
            });
    }
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template if:true={showComponentA} >
            <c-cat-api onanswer={handleTimerComplete} ></c-cat-api>
        </template>
        <template if:true={showComponentB} >
            <c-end-screen value1={value1} value2={value2}></c-end-screen>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
    value1;
    value2;
    handleTimerComplete(event) {
        if(event.detail.timeUp){
            this.showComponentA = false;
            this.showComponentB = true;
            this.value1 = event.detail.value1;
            this.value2 = event.detail.value2;
        }else{
            consolole.log('!!error is coming up!!');
        }
    }
```

```
<template>
    <div>correct answers <strong>{value1}</strong></div>
    <div>total number of questions attempted <strong>{value2}</strong> </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, can you please explain it a little bit how we can save the values and pass it to A to B OR how to use slds-hide. It will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @HadiHusain See my edits. This demonstrates the basic options of using either slds-hide or storing the data in the parent.

Comment: Thanks a ton :)